# Printing key when consuming JSON messages using kafka-json-schema-console-consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to consume JSON messages (defined by a JSON Schema) using **kafka-json-schema-console-consumer** and I am not getting the **key** to be parsed/printed (but the value does get printed out) .

I could not find the property flags in any documentation but I am pretty sure I should be able to print the key.  I can confirm that I am producing messages successfully with a JSON schema and that all Kafka components (zookeeper, kafka broker, schema registry are working)

Below is the command I am using.  Is there a way to have the key be printed?

```
kafka-json-schema-console-consumer \
--bootstrap-server http://kafka:9092 \
--topic source-1 \
--property value.schema='
{
  "definitions" : {
    "record:myrecord" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "required" : [ "timestamp", "data" ],
      "properties" : {
        "timestamp" : {"type" : "string"},
        "data" : {"type" : "string"}
      }
    }
  },
  "$ref" : "#/definitions/record:myrecord"
}' \
--property key.schema='
{
  "definitions" : {
    "record:mykey" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "required" : [ "id" ],
      "additionalProperties" : false,
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {"type" : "integer"}
      }
    }
  },
  "$ref" : "#/definitions/record:mykey"
}'
```

The output shows that the value is being printed properly but the key is not being printed:

```
{"timestamp":"10/05/2021 4:41:53 PM","data":"hello world"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `--property print.key=true`